# Returning matched regex & Select-object properties of file where expression matched

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm attempting to match regex and return both the matched expression and the file's object properties where the regex is true.

```
$pattern1 = regex1

$pattern2 = regex2

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -file -force -path "C:\" | ?{ findstr.exe /mprc:. $_.FullName } | where { $_ | Select-String -pattern $pattern1, $pattern2}  | Select-Object -Property FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, Matched regex $pattern* | export-csv -Path c:\temp\Found.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I can get close using:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -Exclude *.*db, *.jpg, *.xps, *.msg, *.bmp, *.xfdl, *.ppt, *.dll, *.rs, *.evtx, *.dat.LOG1, *.dat.LOG2, *.log, *.dat, *.jfm, *.lock, *.pem -ErrorAction $erroractionpref | Select-String -pattern $pattern3, $pattern4 | Select-Object Path, FullName, Extension, BaseName, LineNumber, line, LastWriteTime
```

However I've been unable to output the string the regex matched on, along with the file's object properties.

Sample output: FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, MatchedRegex$Pattern, Extension, BaseName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying what issues you are having. You are not showing errors and explaining you issue with your code.

If you are trying to do this on anything other than text only files, this will never work.

Why are you calling an exe at all, when you can just use Select-String in both cases?
Why are you mixing aliases?

What is the expectation of this...

```
Matched regex $pattern*
```

... Select-Object will never know what this is, and thus will fail. You must us a legitimate properties (or calculated properties) in a Select.

Running your code, slightly modified, returns that results for the regex patterns specified.

[Findstr details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)

> ```
> # /m Prints only the file name if a file contains a match. 
> # /p Skips files with non-printable characters. 
> # /r Processes search strings as regular expressions. This is the default setting. 
> # /c:<String> Uses the specified text as a literal search string.
> ```

```
$pattern1 = 'localhost'
$pattern2 = 'COMPUTERNAME'

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -file -force -path "E:\Temp" | 
Where-Object { findstr.exe /mprc:. $PSItem.FullName } | 
where-Object { $PSItem | Select-String -pattern $pattern1, $pattern2 }  | 
Select-Object -Property FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime

# Results

FullName                                       CreationTime          LastWriteTime        
--------                                       ------------          -------------        
E:\Temp\available13.html.2019-03-26_081523.bak 4/1/2019 9:22:45 AM   3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM
E:\Temp\hostlist.txt                           3/27/2019 11:36:53 PM 3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM
E:\Temp\index.html.2019-03-26_081538.bak       4/1/2019 9:22:49 AM   3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM
E:\Temp\Servers.txt                            5/8/2019 2:52:29 PM   5/10/2019 3:52:20 PM
```

Leaving the last bit ...

```
Matched regex $pattern*
```

will give you this ...

```
$Error | Format-List -Force


Exception             : System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The variable '$pattern' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
                           at System.Management.Automation.VariableOps.GetVariableValue(VariablePath variablePath, ExecutionContext 
                        executionContext, VariableExpressionAst varAst)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
TargetObject          : pattern
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (pattern:String) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 4
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

***Update for the OP follow-up***

```
# Change the select to all possible properties ...

$pattern1 = 'localhost'
$pattern2 = 'COMPUTERNAME'

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -file -force -path "E:\Temp" | 
Where-Object { findstr.exe /mprc:. $PSItem.FullName } | 
where-Object { $PSItem | Select-String -pattern $pattern1, $pattern2 }  | 
Select-Object -Property *
```

... you will see that is never returned, and thus you can't retrieve it, because it is never passed in your code and cannot be return by the way you have this coded.

You also, must take into consideration that that pattern match can be one or more of the patterns you pass in, so, with that, it is not a single entry per line, it's an array. So, now you'd need to decide how you want that output to look, when all patterns are matched.

For Example, modifying your code to deal to capturing that pattern, does give the output ...

*(Now, this is just a quick kludge, not elegant.)*

```
$pattern1 = 'localhost'
$pattern2 = 'COMPUTERNAME'

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -file -force -path "E:\Temp" | 
Where-Object { findstr.exe /mprc:. $PSItem.FullName } | 
where-Object { $PatternMatch = (Select-String -pattern $pattern1, $pattern2 -Path $PSItem.FullName )
Select-String -pattern $pattern1, $pattern2 -Path $PSItem.FullName 
}  | 
Select-Object -Property FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, 
@{Name = 'PatternMatch';Expression = {$PatternMatch.Pattern}}

# Results

FullName                                       CreationTime          LastWriteTime         PatternMatch             
--------                                       ------------          -------------         ------------             
E:\Temp\available13.html.2019-03-26_081523.bak 4/1/2019 9:22:45 AM   3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM {COMPUTERNAME, localhost}
E:\Temp\hostlist.txt                           3/27/2019 11:36:53 PM 3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM {COMPUTERNAME, localhost}
E:\Temp\index.html.2019-03-26_081538.bak       4/1/2019 9:22:49 AM   3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM {COMPUTERNAME, localhost}
E:\Temp\Servers.txt                            5/8/2019 2:52:29 PM   5/10/2019 3:52:20 PM  localhost
```

... now, is that the look you want for that last column or did you want one line per pattern match, so, all things would be a single entry per column?

If you are looking at the 1:1 match up, meaning, displaying the file multiple times per the match, then you'd end up needing an explicit loop effort.

For Example:

```
$pattern1 = 'localhost'
$pattern2 = 'COMPUTERNAME'

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -file -force -path "E:\Temp" | 
Where-Object { findstr.exe /mprc:. $PSItem.FullName } | 
ForEach { 
    Select-String -pattern $pattern1, $pattern2 -Path $PSItem.FullName | 
    Select-Object -Property Path, Pattern, 
    @{Name = 'CreationDate';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $PSItem.Path).CreationTime}},
    @{Name = 'LastWriteTime';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $PSItem.Path).LastWriteTime}}
} 


# Results

Path                                           Pattern      CreationDate          LastWriteTime        
----                                           -------      ------------          -------------        
E:\Temp\available13.html.2019-03-26_081523.bak COMPUTERNAME 4/1/2019 9:22:45 AM   3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM
E:\Temp\available13.html.2019-03-26_081523.bak localhost    4/1/2019 9:22:45 AM   3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM
E:\Temp\hostlist.txt                           COMPUTERNAME 3/27/2019 11:36:53 PM 3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM
E:\Temp\hostlist.txt                           localhost    3/27/2019 11:36:53 PM 3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM
E:\Temp\index.html.2019-03-26_081538.bak       COMPUTERNAME 4/1/2019 9:22:49 AM   3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM
E:\Temp\index.html.2019-03-26_081538.bak       localhost    4/1/2019 9:22:49 AM   3/27/2019 11:37:33 PM
E:\Temp\Servers.txt                            localhost    5/8/2019 2:52:29 PM   5/10/2019 3:52:20 PM
```

Comment: My goal is to add the "Matched Pattern" to the #Results table in your example above. That way when I output to csv I can tell which one of the two regex expressions matched a string, and what the string was that matched one of the regex. FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, Matched Pattern

Comment: Your bottom example is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.